# How can you install ubuntu to a thumb drive in windows, without having to run an application which requires administrator priveleges?

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, windows-10, iso, fat32

Just a bit of backstory, I am at a work-search office today on one of their computers and it has no permissions whatsoever, making their computers nigh impossible to use for me, particularly because I use a highly customed keyboard layout only available in Linux.

I have my thumb-drive today however, and thought I would make a bootable-usb that I can work from instead. The thing is, is that without any permissions, I can not run any of the USB thumb drive installers, and so I am trying to figure out how to do this manually. I already have the thumb drive formatted to Fat, so is it just a matter of copying the ISO contents to the drive? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that booting from your thumb drive is in accordance with the Terms of Use of "a work-search office"?

Comment: If the computer boots UEFI you should just need to copy the ISO contents to the FAT32 formatted USB drive.

Comment: @C.S.Cameron https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189020/how-can-i-get-a-live-only-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10-and-newer-versions kinda disagrees with that idea.

Comment: @K7AAY : I understand that sudodus is talking "cloned" drives, such as "Startup Disk Creator" and "mkusb Live only" make as ISO9660. Limited to 19.10 and later. See his comments on this page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

Comment: @K7AAY, I think C.S.Cameron is right: If the computer boots in UEFI mode, you should just need to copy the ISO contents to the FAT32 formatted USB drive (and you do *not* need administrator priveleges to do it).

Comment: See also the following link [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb) and scroll down to 'Do it yourself'.

Answer (score 3):

### To Confirm Ability to Create Live/Persistent USB in Windows 10 Without Administrator permissions

- Format flash drive to as new state, (FAT32)
- Open the 19.10 ISO in Windows 10 File Explorer and copy the contents to the flashdrive.

### Persistence

There are several methods to make the flash drive persistent. Using a casper-rw partition is not limited to 4GB.

**Alt 1**

- Boot the drive using UEFI
- At the grub menu press "e" to edit the menu
- Add a space and "toram" after ..quiet splash,,,
- Open GParted, select the USB drive, unmount and Resize/Move to make room for a persistent partition
- In the available space create an ext4 partition and label it casper-rw
- Mount grub.cfg. In Terminal run

  sudo mkdir -p /mnt/sd1

  sudo mount /dev/sdx1 /mnt/sd1

Where x is the OS partition

- As root edit boot/grub/grub.cfg by adding a space and the word persistent after the first ...quiet splash --- and save.

**Alt 2**

- Open Boot/grub/grub.cfg in Windows 10 latest build
- After quiet splash ---, type a space and "persistent"
- Boot the drive using UEFI
- At the grub menu press "e" to edit the menu
- Change "persistent" to "toram"
- Open GParted, select the USB drive, unmount and Resize/Move to make room for a persistent partition
- In the available space create an ext4 partition and label it casper-rw

**The drive should now be ready for work**

- You can create a new user and install programs as you wish.

Comment: Edit `grub.cfg` in the live system as described at [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy#Edit_grub.cfg](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb/diy#Edit_grub.cfg) in Linux. But it would be good if you test and verify a method that works directly in Windows (without getting problems because of the different code between each line (newline in linux, carriage-return + newline in Windows) in text files.

Comment: @sudodus. Had a little mental blockage last night. Above method is now working OK, Thanks. I was able to edit grub.cfg in Win10.

Comment: @sudodus, I think it may still need a little testing. Looks fine in Notepad with Build 18363, but compacted in Build 17134. Perhaps editing while open in toram might be best.

Comment: I agree, that editing while running live with toram might be best. And I think it is a good idea to make people aware of possible problems when editing in Windows because of different coding of line breaks (newline in linux, carriage-return + newline in Windows).

Comment: @sudodus It works for sure and it is not that much more work.