# How can I get a live-only drive with Ubuntu 19.10 and newer versions?

Tags: live-usb

I have cloned from the Ubuntu family iso files to USB pendrives, and the result has been live (live-only) drives, where nothing can be saved past shutdown and reboot.

**But an Ubuntu 19.10 live drive cloned from the iso file creates and writes to a `casper-rw` partition**. It seems to be a new feature.

- How can this happen and how can I avoid that and get a live-only drive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Cloned drive

A cloned drive, created with the 'Startup Disk Creator' in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
or newer versions, has a hybrid iso9660 file system, which works both in
DVDs and USB pendrives (and memory cards), but it is read-only by design,
so you cannot edit anything in it. Also 'Disks' alias `gnome-disks`, and
'mkusb' (when cloning and creating live-only drives) make USB drives with
a hybrid iso9660 file system.

### But a cloned Ubuntu 19.10+ live drive is not really live-only

> Isn't *live* the default for a cloned drive?

Well, it used to be, and it is still live but not live-only in 19.10.

The default action is that a `casper-rw` partition is created automatically
and it is mounted to `/var/crash` and `/var/log`, so that some of the things
you are doing are logged.

- This is good for debugging for example when there are problems during
  the installation of Ubuntu into an internal drive,
- but you may want to use a live-only drive for payments and other tasks
  where you want highest possible security and privacy.

### How to make your USB boot drive with Ubuntu 19.10+

- There is a new feature in the casper package in Ubuntu 19.10. It makes it
  much easier to create and use a `casper-rw` partition for persistence, in other words
  to make a persistent live drive.
- This feature is also used to create logs for debugging when the drive is
  running live (without the boot option `persistent`).
- You can *edit your binary iso file* and replace the cosmetic boot options
  `quiet splash` with the boot option `'persistent  '` or `'nopersistent'`
  (the strings contain 12 characters, so the replacement can be done without
  any offset in the following part(s) of the iso file. You can do it with `sed`

  ```
  sed 's/quiet splash/persistent  /' standard.iso > persistent.iso
  sed 's/quiet splash/nopersistent/' standard.iso > nopersistent.iso
  ```

  and clone the modified iso file, or flash directly with

  ```
  sed 's/quiet splash/persistent  /' standard.iso > /dev/sdx
  sed 's/quiet splash/nopersistent/' standard.iso > /dev/sdx
  ```

  where x is the device letter for the USB pendrive.

### You can *do it with a safety belt* using [`mkusb-plug`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/plug)

Here we focus on **'No-persistent live drive'** in order to make a purely live-only drive, where nothing will be preserved after shutdown and reboot.