# Should I Set my Ubuntu Desktop Bootable USB As Readonly?

Tags: live-usb, read-only

I just created a Ubuntu Desktop Bootable USB which I intend to use in an infected computer.

Should I make it readonly?

If yes, could you point me to documentation that guides me through the process?

Comment: An normal Ubuntu Installer LiveUSB .iso image is already Read-Only (do NOT enable persistence). However an *installed Ubuntu system* on USB cannot be made read-only - it will promptly crash. It's not clear from your description which you are asking about.

Comment: It may be already read only depending on how you created the bootable USB. Try moving a file from the USB and see if it works. If it is not read only, please [update](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1207687/edit) your question and describe how you created the bootable USB.

Comment: The previous comments apply to Ubuntu 18.04.x LTS. But if you have Ubuntu 19.10 (or a newer version), you should consider making a really read-only drive according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189020/how-can-i-get-a-live-only-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10-and-newer-versions).