# Unattended casper-rw

Tags: live-usb

I created an Ubuntu 19.10 usb stick and I use this usb to boot live Ubuntu 19.10.
Today when I want to format this stick I discovered there is a casper-rw partion, but I didn't make persistent usb.

I created this usb via `cp` command.

Please have you any tips why is this partion icluded on usb?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new feature of Ubuntu 19.10. That partition is there to store logged data, that can be used in order to debug problems during boot but also during installation (into an internal drive).

See the following links,

- [How is it easier to make a persistent live drive with Ubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181854/how-is-it-easier-to-make-a-persistent-live-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10)
- [How can I get a live-only drive with Ubuntu 19.10 and newer versions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189020/how-can-i-get-a-live-only-drive-with-ubuntu-19-10-and-newer-versions)

Comment: Thank you very much for answer.

Comment: @MartinG. You are welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Creating a NTFS Data Partition on a Startup Disk Creator, balenaEtcher or Similar ISO9660 USB

Since 19.10 the process of cloning an OS to USB as done by Startup Disk Creator, creates a casper-rw partition.

This partition can be used for persistence by pressing shift at boot and esc, then F6 and esc again. then typing a space and the word "persistent".

This must be done every boot where persistence in wanted.

It is possible to modify the ISO file used by SDC to include the word persistence into grub, but it is not easy.

**If the Ubuntu install is mainly needed for installing Ubuntu, the casper-rw partition can easily be converted to a NTFS partition, that can be used for Data storage by both Linux and Windows.**

**Procedure**

- Run Startup Disk Creator or Etcher to create Live 19.10, (or later), USB
- Boot new Live USB to activate casper-rw partition, then Power Off.
- Reboot the Live USB **toram**. (press shift when booting, hit F6 and type a space and toram).
- Unmount casper-rw partition using Disks.
- Open Terminal and run:

  sudo mkfs.ntfs -f -L data /dev/sdx3

were x is the drive number of the new Live USB

[image]

The drive should now have the original data space minus the size of the OS ISO.